# Join two columns imported by IMPORTXML and use the "&&&&&" delimiter between the values of each row (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The data imported by IMPORTXML comes in two different columns, I want to merge the text from Column 1 with Column 2:

Example:

```
textone      texttwo  
textthree    textfour
```

Expected result:

```
textone&&&&&textwo  
textthree&&&&&textfour
```

Formula currently used:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(hlookup(1,{1;IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eerste-divisie/20202021/regular-season/r57945/","//td[@class='team team-a'] | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a | //td[@class='team team-a']/a/@href | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a/@href"))},(row(A:A)+1)*2-transpose(sort(row(A1:A2)+0,1,0)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little regex magic. Assuming everything in the second column starts with "/teams":

```
=TRANSPOSE(
    SPLIT(
        JOIN(,
            ArrayFormula(
                REGEXREPLACE(
                    IMPORTXML(
                        "https://int.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eerste-divisie/20202021/regular-season/r57945/",
                        "//td[@class='team team-a'] | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a | //td[@class='team team-a']/a/@href | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a/@href"
                    ),
                    "(/teams.*)",
                    "&&&&&$1;"
                )
            )
        ),
        ";"
    )
)
```